# Unpermitted parameter for :user when adding Devise custom fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have 2 types of Users: Normal users and pros.

Pros are Users, but have extra fields in a separate table called `:pros`.

So , I did a separate registration form for `:pros`, in which I included :users fields, and added a `fields_for` with the new `:pro` fields.

I also added those new parameters to application_controller, so that devise permits them.

When submiting the registration form, the user is created, but I get the following error in my logs:

```
Started POST "/users" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-11-13 00:53:43 +0100
Processing by RegistrationsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"zUVLJFHhShoHvUVneGNmCf46E4KPWaINeTw4o7iCa7w=", "user"=>{"name"=>"asdasd", "email"=>"asdasd@sss.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "pros"=>{"type"=>"Marca de Decoración", "web"=>"asadasd", "telephone"=>"765876", "about"=>"sadasd"}, "tos_agreement"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"Registrarme y aplicar para PRO"}
Unpermitted parameters: pros
```

**My view is:**

```
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
                <%= f.label :name, "Nombre de usuario" %>
                    <%= f.text_field :name, :autofocus => true %>
                    <%= f.label :email %>
                    <%= f.email_field :email %>
                    <%= f.label :password %>
                    <%= f.password_field :password %>
                    <%= f.label :password_confirmation %>
                    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>

            <%= f.fields_for :pro do |pro| %> 
                <%= pro.select :type,["Marca de Decoración","Tienda de Decoración","Blogger"] %>
                <%= pro.text_field :web, placeholder: "http://www.miweb.com" %>
                <%= f.label :telephone, "Teléfono" %>
                <%= pro.text_field :telephone, placeholder: "Teléfono", label: "Teléfono de contacto" %>
                <%= pro.text_field :about%>
            <% end %>
```

**Users Controller new action**

```
def pro_new
    render "devise/registrations/new-pro-registration"
    @user = User.create
end
```

**My model relations:**

**User.rb**

```
 has_one :pro
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :pro, allow_destroy: true
```

**Pro.rb**

`belongs_to :user`

**My application controller:**

```
 def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:name, :tos_agreement, :avatar, :avatar_cache, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, pros_attributes: [:pro_name, :pro_image, :is_active, :web, :user_id, :about, :facebook, :twitter, :linkedin, :telephone]) }
  end
```

Comment: Check the singular and plural part of pro and pros in your controller

Answer (score 1):

I completely agree with @smallbutton.com
You need to change pro_attributes instead of pros_attributes. you can use params.require(:user).permit! if you want to accept all the params.

Answer (score 1):

You have association like user has_one :pro.

Then you have passed array in permitted parameters but it is has_one relation.

It should be like this.

```
def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:name, :tos_agreement, :avatar, :avatar_cache, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, pro_attributes: (:pro_name, :pro_image, :is_active, :web, :user_id, :about, :facebook, :twitter, :linkedin, :telephone)) }
end
```

It will works :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your controller to this so that a new instance of pro is build and your form helper should produce `pro_attributes`. I assume this is the new action so you dont call #create but #new on your user. Maybe you need to change `pros_attributes` to `pro_attributes` in the permitted_parameters method because its a has_one relation.

```
def pro_new
    @user = User.new
    @user.build_pro
    render "devise/registrations/new-pro-registration"
end
```

Hope this will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I could give you a quick answer, but I think your design needs some work. You'd be far better of (especially in the long run) with the following format using [single table inheritance](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#label-Single+table+inheritance) and [delegations](http://apidock.com/rails/Module/delegate)

```
User #(base class)
  has_one :userInfo
  delegate :list_of_pro_fields, to: :userInfo

BasicUser < User #(sub class)

Pro < User #(sub class)
  validates presence: true, [:list_of_pro_fields]

UserInfo #(base class)
  belongs_to :user
```

While you *could* put the relationship between `Pro` and `ProInfo` I'd keep it on the base class if a user is able to lose (and regain) their pro status. This will prevent orphan records in UserInfo of ex-Pros.

This is also going to result in far better data segregation and response times as many fields you wont need a lot of the time are being moved to a separate table which can be joined as required.